# Serialize json for its sample as a string

Tags: swift

i'm trying to serialize a json but i have an error could someone give me a guide please i'm doing wrong i'm new to swift[enter image description here][1]

```
 let code = "00001"
        let firstName = "Joe"
        let lastName = "Doe"
        let middleName = "Mc."
        let age = 100
        let weight = 45

        let jsonObject: [String: [String:Any]] = [
            "code": code, <----  Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected dictionary value type '[String : Any]'
            "attributeMap": [
                "first_name": firstName,
                "middle_name": middleName,
                "last_name": lastName,
                "age": age,
                "weight": weight
            ]
        ]
        if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: .prettyPrinted),
            let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("===>   \(str)")
        }
```

--I would like a result like this JSON format

{
"code": "00001",
"attributeMap": {
"first_name": "Joe",
"middle_name": "Mc",
"last_name": "Doe",
"age": "23",
"weight": "home.zul"
}
}

Comment: `let jsonObject: [String: [String:Any]]`=> `let jsonObject: [String: Any]` should be the fix. For the rest, you can use `Codable`, it's more Swift (in Swift4+).

Answer (score 1):

If it repeatable operation I will prefer to use more "swifty" way. Let's define two structs

**Person**

```
struct Person: Encodable {
    // Keys

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case middleName = "middle_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case age
        case weight
    }

    // Properties

    let firstName: String

    let middleName: String

    let lastName: String

    let age: Int

    let weight: Double
}
```

The next one

**Entity**

```
struct Entity: Encodable {
    // Keys

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case code
        case person = "attributeMap"
    }

    // Properties

    let code: String

    let person: Person
}
```

**Usage**

```
let person = Person(
    firstName: "Joe",
    middleName: "Mc.",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 100,
    weight: 45
)

let entity = Entity(
    code: "200",
    person: person
)

if
    let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(entity),
    let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
{
    // Do something

}
```

**Result**

```
{"attributeMap":{"age":100,"last_name":"Doe","middle_name":"Mc.","weight":45,"first_name":"Joe"},"code":"200"}
```